# Response is null Created NsDictionary

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have Array from which I get value of abstract which is under NewsValue

```
(
{
    NewsId = 12;
    NewsValue = "{\n    abstract = \"Today P.M of India Mr. Narender Modi visited  for the eve of Agarasen \\njayanti
\\n\";\n    created = 1444733102;\n    imgUrl = \"\";\n    nid = 12;\n    title = \"Latest news\";\n}";
    Title = "Latest news";
}
)
```

I want to converted NewsValue in Dictionary .

```
 NSData *data = [[[tableDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"NewsValue"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                                       error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@",jsonResponse);
```

They give response Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on your own. You need to write code here.

You received an actual string

```
"{\n    abstract = \"Today P.M of India Mr. Narender Modi visited  for the eve of Agarasen \\njayanti
\\n\";\n    created = 1444733102;\n    imgUrl = \"\";\n    nid = 12;\n    title = \"Latest news\";\n}"
```

that itself contains data in some non-standard format (which looks a bit similar to JSON, but is definitely *not* JSON, so NSJSONSerialization will not have the slightest chance to handle it).

If it is possible at all, go to the people writing the code on the server who produced this rubbish, and tell them to send proper JSON, not JSON containing a string with data in a non-standard format. If you can't do that, you'll have to write code to do it all yourself.

BTW. This string looks suspiciously like what NSLog would output for an NSDictionary. Check where the string comes from. Maybe someone has done something stupid in your own code.